# List categories alphabetically

Tags: category, category-tree

I need to have the categories list display alphabetically by default.  I have a large number of categories/sub-categories and list them in various ways around the site.  How can I always have the categories list alphabetically?

Thank you

Comment: you can get all their names, put them in an array and sort them with `sort($array)` and then foreach item in the array display the category

Comment: Try 

http://iamvikram.com/magento-sort-top-menu-categories-and-its-sub-categories-by-name-alphabetically/

Answer (score 1):

There may be lot of ways to achieve this. In my method I am going to `rewrite` a core model file, so that it will set the *layered navigation filter array*
with sorted category array.

What is *layered navigation filter array* ? Sounds confusing. Then I will explain it little bit.

`app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml` is the starting point of layered navigation blocks. In that file you can see that, it invokes below method

```
 <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
```

to show the layered navigation content. This method is defined in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` class and the file is in the location `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php`. Let us analyze this method.

```
public function getFilters()
{
    $filters = array();
    if ($categoryFilter = $this->_getCategoryFilter()) {
        $filters[] = $categoryFilter;
    }

    $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
    foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
        $filters[] = $this->getChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter');
    }


    return $filters;
}
```

I called `$filters` as *layered navigation filter array*. From above code you can see that `category filtering` and `attribute filtering` are storing into this array seperately.

We are interested in category filtering. The main actions of category filtering happens in Model file. The model file that we interested in is `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php`. Take a look on `_getItemsData()` in that file.

```
<?php
protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        $key = $this->getLayer()->getStateKey().'_SUBCATEGORIES';
        $data = $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->getCacheData($key);

        if ($data === null) {
            $categoty   = $this->getCategory();
            /** @var $categoty Mage_Catalog_Model_Categeory */
            $categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();

            $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()
                ->addCountToCategories($categories);

            $data = array();

            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                if ($category->getIsActive() && $category->getProductCount()) {
                    $data[] = array(
                        'label' => Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                        'value' => $category->getId(),
                        'count' => $category->getProductCount(),
                    );
                }
            }

            $tags = $this->getLayer()->getStateTags();
            $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->saveCacheData($data, $key, $tags);
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

From the above code, you can see that `$data` is a multidimensional array that holds an **UNSORTED** arrays as its sub-arrays. We need to sort them in order to achieve our goal. In order to do that, I am gonna create a small module that overwrite this model and sort `$data` array.

1. **config.xml**

**Location :`app/etc/code/local/Programmerrkt/Layerednav/etc/config.xml`**

```
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Programmerrkt_Layerednav>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Programmerrkt_Layerednav>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <!-- Model rewrite-->
                    <layer_filter_category>Programmerrkt_Layerednav_Model_Layer_Filter_Category</layer_filter_category>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

`config.xml` tells to magento that I am going to overwrite the core model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category`.

1. **Programmerrkt_Layerednav.xml**

**Location :`app/etc/modules/Programmerrkt_Layerednav.xml`**

```
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Programmerrkt_Layerednav>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Programmerrkt_Layerednav>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This file activates our module.

1. **Category.php**

**Location :`app/etc/code/local/Programmerrkt/Layerednav/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php`**

```
<?php

class Programmerrkt_Layerednav_Model_Layer_Filter_Category extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category {
    /**
     * Get data array for building category filter items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        $key = $this->getLayer()->getStateKey().'_SUBCATEGORIES';
        $data = $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->getCacheData($key);

        if ($data === null) {
            $categoty   = $this->getCategory();
            /** @var $categoty Mage_Catalog_Model_Categeory */
            $categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();

            $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()
                ->addCountToCategories($categories);

            $data = array();

            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                if ($category->getIsActive() && $category->getProductCount()) {
                    $data[] = array(
                        'label' => Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                        'value' => $category->getId(),
                        'count' => $category->getProductCount(),
                    );
                }
            }

            function cmp($a, $b)
        {
            return strcmp($a["label"], $b["label"]);
        }
        usort($data, "cmp");
            $tags = $this->getLayer()->getStateTags();
            $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->saveCacheData($data, $key, $tags);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Section that sorts `$data` array is

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["label"], $b["label"]);
}
usort($data, "cmp");
```

Thats it. Clear cache and then load your pages.

**Note:** This is for sorting category listing in `layered navigation`

Thanks